# Whatsapp data storage - all data stored locally on phone?

Tags: android, storage, whatsapp

Its possible to receive a huge number of images/text if you are part of Whatsapp groups. Are these stored locally on my phone ?

I'm able to continuously "Load earlier messages" even when the  phone isnt connected to internet so  these must be stored locally. Is there a way to keep images in the server.. maybe this way the images can be of higher resolution too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **Images**, like all media and messages received through WhatsApp, are stored locally. They're stored in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/` and can't in any way be saved on a server.

In **iOS**, the files are in `/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/*/Message/Media` (where * is the whatsApp folder).  You need to have jailbreak to access the folder.

Answer (score 6):

In WhatsApp, all the data will be stored in your device. Any message and image will get stored in your phone. Both chat history and images will be stored in a database on the device and images will be visible through the gallery within a folder named WhatsApp.

If you delete any image from the WhatsApp folder in the gallery, you won't be able to see the deleted image in WhatsApp anymore. Looking at a chat's history, the deleted image will look blurred, and clicking on it you will result in an error message saying "sorry this media file doesn't exist on your SD card".